# When is $R/Soc(R)$ reduced?

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, noncommutative-algebra, noncommutative-rings

Let $R$ be a ring with identity. It is readily checked that when the quotient $R/S_r$ is reduced, the nilpotent elements of $R$ fall into $S_r$, where $S_r$ is the right socle of $R$. Is the converse true? That is, whenever $S_r$ contains the nilpotent elements of $R$, is $R/S_r$ necessarily reduced? Thanks for any cooperation!

Comment: $R/S_{r}$ is reduced, means for me that no non-zero nilpotent is in $R/S_{r}$, i.e. all non-zero nilpotent are in $S_{r}$. 
Conversely, If $S_{r}$ contains all nilpotents, then in $R/S_{r}$ all nilpotents falll into zero, and hence $R/S_{r}$ is reduced. Did I missed something?

Comment: @EvgenyKuznetsov For commutative rings, sure, but why should $x^n\in S_r$ imply $x\in S_r$ *in a noncommutative ring*, even knowing all the nilpotent elements of $R$ lie in $S_r$?